# .eml files being created in c:\

Tags: exchange-2007

I've a number of .eml files appearing in the root of c:\ of an Exchange 2007 server running on 2008 x64.

The file names are like 'skip-b2b5bce4-6a79-4ec2-a38d-130b5abf61cc-8b6b246b-8624-4621-8517-9d2462ae0340.eml', and exist over the last month since 2k7 has been deployed.

What's the best way to track where these are coming from and deal with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bad configuration of GFI Mail Security.  Re-running the config tool corrected the problem.